# Simple histogram issue in R

Tags: r, histogram

I met a simple problem while creating a histogram:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5) ; hist(a,freq = FALSE)
```

I expected 5 bars that have the same height but got this result:

[image: historgram plot with four bars and the first bar double as high as others]

Can you guys please explain why this histogram looks like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Behind the scenes, `hist` is binning your numeric data into ranges.

For each bin except the first, the lower end of the range is exclusive, and the upper is inclusive. So though 1-2 includes 1 and 2, 2-3 includes 3 but not 2, 3-4 includes 4 but not 3, etc.  You can set your own bins like this:

```
hist(a, breaks = 0:max(a), freq = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: @Daeyoon You're welcome! If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. If you think it was a good answer or you'd like to thank me, please upvote it :) See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers